# How do you close/stop tab in vimscript?

Tags: vim, neovim

I use a command in a function like the one below:

```
execute "normal! i\begin\r\<tab>somethinghere\r\\end"
```

and I am expecting this result:

```
\begin
    somethinghere
\end
```

But instead I get:

```
\begin
    somethinghere
    \end
```

How do I "stop" the tab?

Comment: `normal` is just applying keystrokes like you would in normal mode, and you're entering insert mode, which is no different than typing in Vim. Vim's indenting is notoriously terrible, but it looks correct here to indent the second line. You can either add a `<bs>` to remove the indent, or try adding another line break afterwards to see if it unindents.

Comment: Thanks! `\<bs>` solves it!